# Is there any way to see when my attribute was set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Without adding more columns to my DB and doing some callbacks, is there any way (rails-y or otherwise) that I can see when an attribute was initially set on my object?

Comment: If you can use paper_trail gem, and include in your model it manages the version history for the model changes along with time of creation and who did it. But it creates a separate table named versions. Not sure if it would help you in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Postgres* does keep some column-level statistics, updated when an `ANALYZE` is done or an *auto-analyze* occurs. These include things like the *Most Common Values* and *Histogram Bounds*.

However, these are for the column as a whole, across all rows. If you want to have information about an individual row's columns, you'll need to add either additional rows to the table, or create another table (or several) to store the additional information, and in either case update the tracking information accordingly.

These types of audit trails can be automated to some degree by the use of *trigger functions* to examine what's being changed, and if one of the columns you're interested in has changed, you can automatically update the timestamp (if inline in the table) or insert a row in your audit table(s).

However, there is not anything built in at the granularity at which you appear to be looking.

If you are just looking for this for one or a handful of attributes, adding a column inline to the table and updating it (in the insert/update themselves, or via a trigger function), is likely your best bet.

If you are looking for something more systemic, i.e. you want to know this for *all* columns in a bunch of tables, then a more full-fledged auditing system implemented via *trigger functions* and stored in separate tables is probably a better bet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, override the setter method `attribute=` and use `write_attribute` to set it's value.  This should fall into rails-y category:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def attribute_to_override=(value)
    Rails.logger.debug { "attribute_to_override changes to: #{value}." }
    write_attribute(:attribute_to_override, value)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm looking for something more along the lines of `obj.attr.created_at`. This is for a data export, I need to know when a field was set because **insert arbitrary product team reason here**, and I'd rather not go digging through the log to find this data.

Comment: Do you have that data?, the default `created_at` and `updated_at` are not reliable for a single attribute unless the model is single attributed model.

Comment: I don't think that data is stored anywhere. I can't use the objects created/updated at. I'm looking to see if I can dig into the DB to find if it is stored on the specific attribute. Like how you can ask if an attribute has `changed?`, I want to know *when* it was changed. But the more I dig into it, the less it looks like that sort of thing is stored.

Comment: I am sensing an unfortunate end, sorry.  If I understand your requirement correctly, which I think I do, that information is not stored by the framework, you had to have some way of storing that.  If you have access to the logs, you should be able to filter what you want out!